# How to convert to string in Python

Tags: python

How to convert `\x03a`, `\x03d`, `0\x16` to string in Python?

I searched the web but cannot find the solution.

Can anyone please help?

Thank you.

Comment: use [`encode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode)

Comment: What is your Python version ?

Comment: My version is Python 3.6

Answer (score 0):

The default string type in Python3 is Unicode.
You can verify this by writing `type(u'\x03a')` in the `Python3` interpreter.
It would give `<class 'str'>` which is the same result as would be if you write `type('\x03a')`.

To convert the `Python3 string` to `bytecode`, you may use `your_string.encode()`.

For information regarding the encode function, you may follow this link.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=encode#str.encode

You may also convert the Unicode string to bytecode by writing `b'your_string'`

Also, if you just want to print these characters without the Unicode format, you may just write `print('\\x03a')`, i.e. using the backslash escape character.